# Does it mean that there no analytical solution if Mathematica cannot find analytical solution?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm solving simple but coupled ODEs recently. I use both MATLAB symbolic computation and *Mathematica*.

For example, my coupled ODE is the following
\begin{align*}
&\dot{x}(t)=y(t)-\rho b\frac{x(t)}{1-\rho(1-e^{-t})}\\
&\dot{y}(t)=-y(t)+\rho b\frac{x(t)}{1-\rho(1-e^{-t})}\\
\end{align*}
where $\rho\in(0,1)$ and $b\in(0,1)$ are given constants and the initial value of this set of ODEs are $x(0)=a$, there $a\in(0,1)$ and $y(0)=0$.

This expression looks simple but these 2 equations are coupled.

First, I tried MATLAB, it generate "Warning: Explicit solution could not be found." explicitly.

Then I tried *Mathematica*,

```
system = {x'[t] == y[t] - c1*c2*x[t]/(1 - c1*(1 - Exp[-t])), 
   y'[t] == -y[t] + c1*c2*x[t]/(1 - c1*(1 - Exp[-t]))};
```

Then I try to solve it via `sol = DSolve[system, {x, y}, t]`.

The thing that I don't understand is that after I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, *Mathematica* only makes my input look nicer, but didn't produce any result or generating any warning message like MATLAB. So I couldn't tell whether it is because *Mathematica* also couldn't find the analytical solution like MATLAB, or it just does not even try to solve the problem since I input something wrong?

This simple coupled ODE drives me crazy these days. Any suggestion, input is deeply appreciated.

If math software couldn't find analytical solution, then is it still possible to analyze the monotonicity of the solution? For example, in this case, it's easy to analyze the case when $t=\infty$ by setting $\dot{x}=0=\dot{y}$ and solve the equations. I can also numerically plot the solution to see the trend, e.g., $x(t)$ is decreasing. But without the explicit functional form of $x(t)$, how can we prove the monotonicity, stuff like that? In general, if the math software fails to find analytical solution, what should we do next?

Comment: The answer to "Does it mean that there no anlytical solution if Mathematica cannot find analytical solution?" is definitely no (i.e. there are definitely analytic solutions that *Mathematica* can't find for all kinds of things). However, those differential equations seem complicated enough that there could easily not be an analytic solution.

Comment: Even if you are unable to derive a closed form solution to your DE, it might still be possible to study the qualitative behavior of the solutions. Have a look at Bender/Orszag for ideas.

Comment: @J.M. Is that book "Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineer"?

Comment: Yes, that. $\phantom{}$

Comment: It's interesting to note that $\dot{x}(t) + \dot{y}(t) = 0$.

Comment: @rcollyer, that's right. It is a nature of my problem. So I think this problem is very symmetric. So that's why I'm so eager to crack it out in closed-form. I think there should be a closed-form solution. But first, I don't know how to let \textit{Mathematica} to generate a similar message as matlab does "warning: no explicit solution found". Then I will stop to solve it analytically. Currently \textit{Mathematica} doesn't generate any message, which still gives me hope to solve it analytically.

Comment: Well, it has the form $\dot{\vec{x}}(t) = \mathbf{A}(t) \vec{x}(t)$, so you could try diagonalizing $\mathbf{A}$ to decouple the two equations.

Comment: If you want to tell Mathematica to do $e^{-t}$, the proper syntax is `Exp[-t]` rather than `exp(-t)`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, it's my typo. But still thank you very much.

Comment: @rcollyer. But since $\textbf{A}(t)$ is time-dependent, the basis transformation that diagonalizes it is likely time-dependent, and so that will introduce new terms from the derivative on the right-hand side that will likely leave the equation coupled.

Comment: @march yes, you end up with $c(t) \dot{y}(t) - \dot{x}(t) = c(t) y(t) - x(t)$ (where $c(t)$ is the coefficient in front of $x(t)$ in the DE) which makes for a messy decoupling. I'd be tempted to bury $c(t)$ in $y(t)$, but I don't see it decoupling nicely even then. Also, I think your [method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111062/52) is superior.

Comment: @KevinKim. Does one of the answers below sufficiently answer your question? If so, please accept it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here, we take advantage of the observation mentioned in a comment that the sum of `x` and `y` is conserved. If we define

```
s[t] == x[t] + y[t]
d[t] == x[t] - y[t]
```

your differential equations become

```
eqns = {s'[t] == 0,
        d'[t] == -(1 + (r b)/(1 - (1 - E^-t) r)) d[t] + (1 - (r b)/(1 - (1 - E^-t) r)) s[t]}
```

*Mathematica* knows how to solve this:

```
First@DSolve[eqns, {s[t], d[t]}, t]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As noted in the comments above, you have $\dot{x} + \dot{y} = 0$, which implies that $x(t) + y(t)$ is a constant;  call it $c_3$.  (Note that in particular, $c_3 = x(0) + y(0)$.)  You can therefore replace `y[t]` with `c3 - x[t]` in your first equation above, and Mathematica can solve that explicitly:

```
reducedsystem = {x'[t] == c3 - x[t] - c1*c2*x[t]/(1 - c1*(1 - Exp[-t]))}
DSolve[reducedsystem, x[t], t]

(* {{x[t] -> -((c3 E^(-t + (c1 c2 Log[-c1 - E^t + c1 E^t])/(-1 + c1)) (-E^t + c1 (-1 + E^t))^(1 - (c1 c2)/(-1 + c1)))/(1 + c1 (-1 + c2))) 
               + E^(-t + (c1 c2 Log[-c1 - E^t + c1 E^t])/(-1 + c1)) C[1]}} *)
```

I'm a little surprised that Mathematica can't do this on its own, to be honest;  but here we are.

Comment: Wait, but now don't we have an unknown c3 in our solution?  Meaning, x[t] is now expressed in terms of a y[t]  that we still don't know what it is.

Comment: $c_3$ can be determined from the initial conditions:  since it's a constant, then $c_3 = x(0) + y(0)$.  I've edited to clarify this.  In general, you'll have two constants of integration for this system;  in my solution, they'll be the $c_3$ I coded in and the `C[1]` generated by Mathematica in the solution.

Comment: oh yes you are right. And in that case it is equal to `a` from the OP.

Answer (score 7):

The non-trivial solution for this system can be obtained by doing this:

```
system = {x'[t] == y[t] - c1*c2*x[t]/(1 - c1*(1 - Exp[-t])), 
   y'[t] == -y[t] + c1*c2*x[t]/(1 - c1*(1 - Exp[-t]))};

DSolve[First[system /. y -> (-x[#] &)], x[t], t]

(*
==> {{x[t] -> 
   E^(-t + (c1 c2 Log[-c1 - E^t + c1 E^t])/(-1 + c1)) C[1]}}
*)
```

All I did here is use the fact that the equations become identical if $y=-x$. That allows us to drop one of the equations.

Comment: As I noted in my comment above, the syntax of the input in the OP is incorrect.  Mathematica will interpret `exp(-t)` as the product of a constant called `exp` with `-t`.

Comment: @Jens This one looks awesome! Let me try to understand the syntax "DSolve[First[system /. y -> (-x[#] &)], x[t], t]"

Comment: @MichaelSeifert oh yes, of course I used the corrected version to get the posted result - just copied the OP's error accidentally.

Comment: @KevinKim the replacement `y -> (-x[#] &)` sets the *function* `y` equal to the *function* `-x`. You can't just use `y -> -x` here because that won't work in the derivative. Hence the more complex notation. `&` declares an (anonymous) function and `#` is the variable placeholder.

Comment: @Jens:  Are you sure that you used the corrected code to get your posted result?  Your posted result has `exp` in it, including in the denominator without an argument.  Also, note that $\dot{x} + \dot{y} = 0$ does not imply that $y = -x$;  there should be an arbitrary constant involved.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert indeed, I still had a copying error in there. I've just copied the whole thing one more time now... and of course I found only an instance of *a* solution, since the question was asking about solvability only. But the approach by march is the best in any case. Mine was just a quick response to show it can be done.